# Do i still need a mac to develop react-native applications for iOS?

Tags: macos, react-native, virtualbox

i need some information. I thought i can only run the app if i install an mac, xcode on windows so i can run an xcode project and install the pod etc.

but now i tested my app which i start to develop without adding/editing the pod's file and it works on a apple phone as well.

so i'm little bit confused, do I have to install a mac on a windows system or not?

because i thought it's important to create an xcode project and install pod to run it on a iOS

thanks for all replies.

Comment: i assume you are on an expo project, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using expo, so yeah, you can now launch your app on an iPhone.

You can read more about expo [here](https://expo.io/).

You will be able to build for ios and android without installing xCode or android studio.

There's some limitations to expo, but you should be able to do a lots without ejecting your project.